# Error on Sending mail asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net

Hi whenever i am trying to send the mail from my application on account creation i get the following error.

User not local; please try a different path. The server response was: Bad Recipient                             at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)

Smtp settings provided by client is all right.When i replace my smtp setting with gmail smtp settings on web.config mail is going smoothly.but when my smtp setting is set to the smtp setting provided by client above error occurs.

I have the folloeing in my web.config.

```
<mailSettings >
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="from addressm" >
        <network defaultCredentials="true" host="hostname" port="25" userName="username" password="password"  />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The email address you are using for the `To` address is does not exist on the SMTP server and was therefore refused.

Make sure you use an email address that exists.

See [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1166797.aspx) forum post for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Bad Recipient error means that address you want to send some mail does not exist. Check it carefully